# Mesh not moving with the armature

Tags: mesh, armature, rigify

I tried using rigify and after parenting it with the mesh and using weight paint it still doesn't seem to move. I'm still a newbie so this is my first model that I've made so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1T58z256-yVLu8i7b5RACKeloV3Tnfhhz/view?usp=sharing

[image: this is my model with the armature]

Answer (score 0):

Congratulations on your first rigged model. There are a few common mistakes but they are easy to fix:

1. The *Body* mesh has 22 duplicated vertices. This will cause the infamous "[Heat Weighting: Failed to find solution for one or more bones](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/15964/107598)" error. You need to remove them with the *Merge By Distance* operation. Select everything in *Edit mode with key <kbd>A</kbd> and press key <kbd>M</kbd>. It's also described in one answer to the linked question.
2. The clothes have flipped normals. This will mess up the calculation of the *Automatic Weights*. You need to flip the faces. See the question: [Bad auto weight paints](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/255069/107598)

Furthermore,

3. The leg bones of the meta rig are X-legs. You need to straighten them else the knee tilts inwards or outwards when the character lifts the leg. See [Rigify leg issue](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/278925/107598) for details.
   [image: legs]
4. The hair strands have around 400,000 vertices. That's very heavy. Consider adding a *Decimate* modifier on the hair strands with the option `Un-Subdivide` and `4` or even `6` levels. The level value should be an even number to maintain the topology. This way you can reduce the number to about 50,000.
5. For these "extensions"/"cloak parts" you can add extra bones to the metarig and define a Rigify [Rig Type](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/rigging/rigify/rig_types/index.html) to create controls in the animation rig. This question may also be interesting for you: [How to make rig that reacts to gravity or seem to behave physically correct?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/41235/107598) might be useful, too.